# Вылет приложения с MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

Использую один MediaPlayer. Даю ему разный звук при нажатии на каждую из 5 кнопок вот так:

```
@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch(v.getId()) {
                case R.id.flats_btn1:
                    flats = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.carrier);
                    flats.start();
                    break;
```

Но хочу, чтобы при нажатии при проигрывании снова на эту кнопку звук не начинал играть, а начинал только после окончания этого звука. Делаю так, но приложение вылетает с ошибкой:

```
@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch(v.getId()) {
                case R.id.flats_btn1:
                    if (!flats.isPlaying())
                    flats = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.carrier);
                    flats.start();
                    break;
```

Как сделать, чтобы приложение не останавливалось?
LogCat:

```
08-13 22:35:45.517: E/AndroidRuntime(937): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-13 22:35:45.517: E/AndroidRuntime(937): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-13 22:35:45.517: E/AndroidRuntime(937): at FragmentFlatsMale.onClick(FragmentFlatsMale.java:122)
08-13 22:35:45.517: E/AndroidRuntime(937): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
08-13 22:35:45.517: E/AndroidRuntime(937): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
08-13 22:35:45.517: E/AndroidRuntime(937): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-13 22:35:45.517: E/AndroidRuntime(937): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-13 22:35:45.517: E/AndroidRuntime(937): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-13 22:35:45.517: E/AndroidRuntime(937): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-13 22:35:45.517: E/AndroidRuntime(937): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-13 22:35:45.517: E/AndroidRuntime(937): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-13 22:35:45.517: E/AndroidRuntime(937): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-13 22:35:45.517: E/AndroidRuntime(937): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-13 22:35:45.517: E/AndroidRuntime(937): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-13 22:35:47.677: I/Process(937): Sending signal. PID: 937 SIG: 9
08-13 22:35:48.517: E/Trace(956): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас `NPE`, вы пытаетесь вызвать метод на ссылке, коя равна `null`. Т.е. нет у вас в коде гарантии того, что на момент опроса преера на предмет того, что он играет сам плеер уже был создан. Плюс, у вас нет скобок для тела `if` и это приводит к тому, что даже если на условии код не упадёт, то он может по тому же `NPE` упасти на строке запуска музыки.

Вам надо проверять существует ли уже плеер и только потом играет ли он.

```
if (flats == null || !flats.isPlaying()) {
    flats = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.carrier);
    flats.start();
}
```